# .filter is not a function Angular2

Tags: angular

i getting an error `EXCEPTION: TypeError: articles.filter is not a function`
in my service

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

 @Injectable()

 export class ArticlesService {
     http:Http;
     constructor(http:Http) {
     this.http = http;
    }

getArticle(id: number) {
return Promise.resolve('./articles.json').then(
  articles => articles.filter(article => article.id === id)[0]
     );
  }
 }
```

[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFYtlbDte83umKgiUcTl?p=preview) but in "Tour of Heroes" it works fine

Comment: You should provide a plnkr of your case not working, the working one is not really useful.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is quite simple. It doesn't work for you because your service resolves with a *string* not an array:

```javascript
getArticle(id: number) {
  return Promise.resolve('./articles.json').then(
    articles => articles.filter(article => article.id === id)[0]
  );
}
```

Note, `Promise.resolve('./articles.json')` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)) which resolves with string.

Correct code would be something like this:

```javascript
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ArticlesService {

  http: Http;

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getArticle(id: number) {
    return this.http.get('./articles.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise()
        .then(articles => articles.filter(article => article.id === id)[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Eagle eye there! Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that it's because in some cases, the content you get isn't an array but an object. So you can't use the `filter` method since it's a method of `Array`.

But I agree with Eric, a plunkr reproducing your error would be great!